# Getting blank while trying to get list of blobs from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to fetch the list of blobs present in the Azure Blob Container from PowerShell.

I have tried using function in my script to do that. But it is returning nothing.

My script is somewhat like this(Hiding names of resources):

```
## Connect to Azure Account  
Connect-AzAccount   

Function GetBlobs  
{  
    ## Get the storage account   
    $storageAcc=Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName     

    ## Get all the containers  
    $containers=Get-AzStorageContainer  

    ## Get all the blobs  
    $blobs=Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName 

    ## Loop through all the blobs  
    foreach($blob in $blobs)  
    {  
        write-host $blob.Name  
    }  
}  
  
GetBlobs
```

But it returned blank though I have blobs in my container. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone help me out? I'm new to this platform too, don't know if I put my question in the right way.

Comment: That doesn't look complete. Your getting a list of all containers using `Get-AzStorageContainer`. In the next step you use the uninitialized variable `$containerName` to access a single one. Did you forget an (outer) loop over all containers?

Comment: I'm giving the name of my container in $containerName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I have tested in my environment. It returned the list of blobs successfully.***

[image: 1]

Try including **`storage account context`**. If you want to know more about this, go through this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-the-azure-storage-context-using-powershell). After including that, you may get the list of blobs successfully.

Please check if your script is something like this:

```
$resourceGroupName = "your_RG"
$storageAccountName= "your_SA"
$containerName= "your_container_name"
 
## Connect to Azure Account  
Connect-AzAccount   
 
## Function to get all the blobs  
Function GetBlobs  
{  
    $storageAcc=Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName     
    ## Get the storage account context  
    $context=$storageAcc.Context  
    ## Get all the containers  
    $containers=Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context      
    $blobs=Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $context
    foreach ($blob in $blobs)  
    {  
        write-host $blob.Name  
    }  
}  
  
GetBlobs
```

Please check the below reference if it is helpful.

**Reference:**

[How to Get All the Blobs from an Azure Storage Account using PowerShell (c-sharpcorner.com)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-get-all-the-blobs-from-azure-storage-account-using-powershell)